# What is this lathe tool that helps me copy a turned object?

Tags: lathe, tool-identification

I want to be able to make very accurate 'copy' of a lathe turned project such as legs on my lathe. I seen this tool on YouTube and have no idea what this is called but looks very useful. But the flaw is you need them holes and some bolts. But I may be able to make the hole needed to do such a thing.

I am sure there are other tools or methods of doing this. And I would like to know what would be the best thing to go with. This one seemed to be a great choice. If anybody can find a link where to get something like this please include it. Or how to make something like it. I am willing to build something if need be.

Basically I want something that will help me make a copy of a turned object.

[image: Tool used to make a copy of turned object]

Comment: From my naive knowledge, I would assume it is a duplicator...

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea where to get one. I am doing some research but not finding anything good. There are some for $300 but are very different. I would LOVE similar to this one. Seems very easy to use.

Comment: I hate to say it because I'm going to sound very contrarian, but I'd suggest you spend the time with templates and hand work. (For one thing -- at least as far as I'm concerned -- lathe work is pure fun!) Practice makes perfect.

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate, I am happy you said something. I have used the neighbors lathe and the schools last year. I love doing stuff on the lathe, best thing in the work shop. I have seen a you-tube video my friend showed me and you make the turned item on the lathe, leaving the ends square. The trace the design onto some wood. It may not be as accurate above, but sounds good. Then cut along the traced line on a band saw. I do not necessarily plan on doing what is above since I do not know how the lathe is. (getting december). may or may not be able to do that specific design.

Comment: I removed the request for plans as that is off topic. Once you get the name of your tool you might be able to figure out existing plans from there. If you have issues with said plans that would be a good start for another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks quite similar to [the CopyTurn](http://www.woodfast.com.au/index.php?p=1_11) - which, as you'll see, is $385 AUD.

Anything substantially less than that and you'll find it's something cheap/homemade/flimsy like [this](http://www.woodsmithplans.com/plan/lathe-duplicator/) or [this](http://www.woodcentral.com/articles/turning/articles_832.shtml)

Everything else will be solid, will attach to your lathe, and will be up in that $300 range, or much higher.

Comment: I am liking the wood-smith one. It would be in my budget (I hate how they ask for so much for a tool like that). And if done right I am sure it works like a charm. Thank you, this does help me a bunch!

Comment: Prices asked for tools ideally should reflect how well they work and how much time and effort they save you,  as well as (and usually more than) their manufacturing cost -- just as for any other product.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount your pattern piece on the lathe, and position a lamp in a fixed location somewhere above the lathe. Then trace thepattern's shadow on a piece of paper below. 
Then you keep the lamp on and stop advancing your tool once the shadow matches the pattern trace. 
With a bit of practice it should be a very close duplicate for the cost of the lamp and the paper. 
I have a lamp that appears to be made for this, in that it has  mount for my lathe. But any lamp ought to work,  depending on other lights in the shop.

Comment: Not a bad Idea. Will have to give it a try, thanks

Comment: This won't work with many point light sources but it's a great ideal in principle.